# can i check to see what application is currently running from a service?

Tags: android, android-activity

I was trying to check to see what application or activity is currently in the foreground/being used by a user from a service i created by doing:

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                        Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

                List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> processList = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
String cProcess = processList.get(0).processName;
```

but this sometimes shows services like com.android.systemui or com.android.buetooth even when a different activity is in the fore ground..

i guess this is checking services instead of activities.. is there a better more reliable way to see what application is currently in the foreground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [`activityManager.getRunningTasks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) is more what you're looking for, although be aware the Android developers warn against using the `ActivityManager` for any core feature for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Try check importance of process:

```
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses= null;
appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
if (appProcesses!=null) {

    for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
        if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
            // Log.d("MYTAG",appProcess.processName+":"+appProcess.importance+" is foreground");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set a service to foreground importance - this won't necessarily filter out services

Comment: sorry dont know flags for services but you may check is this process system or not: boolean issSystem = (p.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 1;//process like com.android.buetooth

Answer (score 0):

this works like a charm.. thank JRaymond:

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                    Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> processList = am.getRunningTasks(3);


            String cProcess = processList.get(0).baseActivity.getPackageName();
```